# Saving associated models in Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a form that collects data about an Article, and I want to save that data, as well as for a model called Abstract, where an Article hasMany Abstracts.  My models look like this:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class AbstractsTable extends Table
{
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->belongsTo('Articles');
}

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('body');
    return $validator;
}
}
```

And

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ArticlesTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->hasMany('Abstracts');
    }

public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        $validator  ->notEmpty('category')
        return $validator;
    }
}
```

My input form has a field named 'abstracts.body', and in my ArticlesController I have this function:

```
  public function add()
  {
          $data = $this->request->data;
          $article = $this->Articles->newEntity($data, [
                            'associated' => ['Abstracts']
                    ]);
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                  $article->user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
                  $data['abstracts']['user_id'] = $article->user_id;
                  $data['abstracts']['approved'] = 0;
                  $article = $this->Articles->patchEntity($article, $data, [ 
                                'associated' => ['Abstracts']
                          ]);

            if ($this->Articles->save($article, [ 'validate' => false,
                                                   'associated' => ['Abstracts']
                                                 ]) )
                 {
                         $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
                         return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
                 }
          $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
          }
          $this->set('article', $article);
  }
```

My Abstracts table is pretty straightforward:

```
CREATE TABLE 'abstracts' ('id' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 'article_id' INTEGER , 'user_id' INTEGER , 'body' TEXT, 'approved' BOOLEAN )
```

From debugging I can see that I have the correct 'abstracts' array within my $data (in add()), but it doesn't appear to ever try to save it to the database.  Can someone please point out my error?  Thanks!

Comment: show a `debug((string)$article) ` before calling save, please

Comment: Saved my day :) The patchEntity() with the associated bit.

Answer (score 4):

Got it.

I started going wrong here:

```
My input form has a field named 'abstracts.body'
```

Because it's a hasMany relationship, I need to have that input be 'abstracts.0.body'

Then the rest of LeWestopher's answer will work-- adding an index to the fields I want to fill in from the Controller, so $data[abstracts][0]['user_id'] => ... and so on.  Thanks!

Comment: Perfect!  Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 3):

You're post processing your $data['abstracts'] array incorrectly resulting in the association not saving.  $data['abstracts'] is expected to be an array of Abstracts.  Your issue lies here:

```
$data['abstracts']['user_id'] = $article->user_id;
$data['abstracts']['approved'] = 0;
```

You should be able to fix this pretty easily by changing this to:

```
foreach($data['abstracts'] as $index => $abstract) {
    $abstract['user_id'] = $article->user_id;
    $abstract['approved'] = 0;
    $data['abstracts'][$index] = $abstract;
}
```

This should correctly iterate over your array of abstracts, set the user_id and approved keys appropriately and then it should save correctly.

[CakePHP 3.x Documentation on Saving Associations](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-hasmany-associations)

**EDIT:** Very interesting issue indeed.  Try it without using patchEntity, and use newEntity by itself instead:

```
public function add()
{

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $data = $this->request->data;

        // Post process abstracts objects
        foreach($data['abstracts'] as $index => $abstract) {
            $abstract['user_id'] = $article->user_id;
            $abstract['approved'] = 0;
            $data['abstracts'][$index] = $abstract;
        }

        // Build newEntity
        $article = $this->Articles->newEntity($data, [
            'associated' => ['Abstracts']
        ]);

        // Save our entity with associations
        if ($this->Articles->save($article, [ 
            'validate' => false,
            'associated' => ['Abstracts']
        ])) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your article has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }

        // On save fail
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your article.'));
        $this->set('article', $article);
    }     
}
```

**EDIT 2:**  Your issue looks like it's definitely in your form helper.  Your current form helper input creates an $data array that looks like this:

```
$data = [
    'abstracts' => [
        'body' => 'example text'
    ],
    'category' => 'Science'
];
```

Which SHOULD look like:

```
$data = [
    'abstracts' => [
        ['body' => 'example text'],
        ['body' => 'Im your second abstract'],
        ['body' => 'Abstract three!']
    ],
    'category' => 'Science'
];
```

The issue lies in:

```
abstracts.body
```

Which should read as (in array dot notation):

```
// abstracts.0.body
echo $this->Form->input('abstracts.0.body', [
    'label' => 'summary of article', 
    'maxlength' =>'440', 
    'rows' => '7'
]);
```

I believe that should be the last issue you run into.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I don't think you're right in that my problem is there (or at the very least, my ONLY problem isn't there).  I know this because I can comment out that whole section and it still doesn't insert.  E.g. 

    //$data['abstracts']['user_id'] = $article->user_id;
    //$data['abstracts']['approved'] = 0;

Acts exactly the same.

My form looks like:
    echo $this->Form->input('abstracts.body', ['label' => 'summary of article', 'maxlength' =>'440', 'rows' => '7']);

Comment: Check my edit to my answer, and if that solution doesn't work, please post a debug() copy of your $data array before processing and after processing.

Comment: Also, this might be irrelevant, but check the $_accessible property in AbstractEntity.php, you might not have your 'body' property set to accessible for setting via mass assignment (with newEntity and patchEntity).  I don't believe this is the case because you have 'validate => false' set on your save function, but I'm not sure if that turns off  validation for the associated entities as well.

Comment: Still doesn't work.  I don't have an Abstract Entity file.  $data = Array
(
    [abstracts] => Array
        (
            [body] => example text
        )

    [category] => Science
)

Comment: And my sql debug shows only: INSERT INTO articles (created, modified, category) VALUES ('2015-05-07 14:40:56', '2015-05-07 14:40:56', 'Science')

Comment: Posted another edit. Looks like the issue was in your formhelper.  Let me know how that works for you.